# Appending last elements of a sublist into a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists where I need to take the last element and append it into a new list.
Small example of the output of my first function:
Context: "data" is the empty dictionary I added the list of lists too btw

```
['PANAMA', ['2006/10/18', '5.0'], ['2006/10/14', '4.8']]
['MISSOURI', ['2006/10/18', '3.4']]
['INDONESIA', ['2006/10/18', '4.9'], ['2006/10/18', '4.9']]
```

The lists come from a file containing earthquake data, Below is my code for the project:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter


def get_list(data, key):
    r_list = [key]
    for i in data:
        if i == key:
            for j in data[key]:
                r_list.append(j)
            break
# Return the list.
   return r_list


def main():
    f = open("earthquakes.txt")
    data = {}
    for line in f.readlines():
        list1 = line.split()
        dat_mag = [list1[1], list1[0]]
    if list1[len(list1) - 1] in data:
        data[list1[len(list1) - 1]].append(dat_mag)
    else:
        data[list1[len(list1) - 1]] = [dat_mag]
    for key in data:
        print(get_list(data, key))

    ric_scale = list(map(itemgetter(-1), islice(data, 1, None)))
    print(ric_scale)

    plt.hist(ric_scale, bins=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

    plt.xlabel('Magnitudes')
    plt.ylabel('Occurrences')
    plt.title('Earthquake Intensity')

    plt.show()


main()
```

I need to get the end values: '5.0', '4.8' etc. This is only a small sample of the file. How would I go about doing this, my code so far is taking the last letter of the country. I need it to go the list with the date and magnitude number.

```
  ric_scale = []
  for sublist in data:
      ric_scale.append(sublist[-1])
```

My expected output would be:

```
[5.0, 4.8, 3.4, 4.9, 4.9]
```

I plan to use the magnitudes to create a histogram in MPL.

Comment: You can use `if type(item) is list` to decide if a list item is itself also a list.

Comment: your input are 3 different list. are all these 3 are in an outer list as well?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, it is consistent

Comment: @Nick I want to create a list of the numbers so I can create a histogram with matplotlib

Comment: @TylaClements that doesn't really clarify it. Could you please [edit] your post with your expected output from the sample data you have provided?

Comment: Adding to @Nick: That sample data isn't syntactically legal as a single data structure. It's three unrelated `list`s (one of which has a trailing comma that would wrap it in a `tuple`). Can you provide the *actual* data structure you're processing, not a handwave? And `data` definitely isn't a dictionary, you're iterating over it and getting values you can index to `-1` directly, without looking up the key in `data`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I added a bit more context just now. The data comes from a file the I opened and turned into a list of lists with the country as first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```py
res = [float(j[-1]) for i in data for j in i if isinstance(j, list)]
```

where `j` is the items from each list (`i`) in `data`.

---

Output:

```
[5.0, 4.8, 3.4, 4.9, 4.9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just skip the first country name by `[1:]` (if indeed the format is consistent)

```
ric_scale = []
  for sublist in data[1:]:
      ric_scale.append(sublist[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for funsies, the no large temporaries solution as a one-liner (ignoring imports):

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter

ric_scale = list(map(itemgetter(-1), islice(data, 1, None)))
```

Explaining piecemeal:

1. `islice(data, 1, None)` makes an iterator that yields all the values from "index" 1 onward (skipping index `0`, the country name without a value).
2. `map(itemgetter(-1), ...)` makes another iterator that efficiently extracts the last element from all the values in the input
3. `list(...)` consumes that iterator to make the final `list` all at once (`[*map(itemgetter(-1), islice(data, 1, None))]` also works, and is trivially faster, using unpacking syntax to make the `list` via syntax instead of the named constructor).

To be clear, there's no guarantee this is faster (and for short inputs, it's going to be slower; the fixed overhead is higher, even if the per-element overhead might be slightly lower).